# Fast, accurate timing for both widget AND app in Android?

Tags: android, widget, timing

I have a widget/app that performs display [draw...()] operations up to 20 times a second (e.g. animation), depending upon user-selected criteria.  When running as a widget, the "full" app is invoked when the widget is touched.  (The full app performs similar display operations but has more bells and whistles than the widget.)  I want to use the same timing mechanism for both the widget and the "full" app but haven't figured out how to manage this.

Widgets seem to rely on AlarmManager, which does not provide sufficiently accurate timing for my purposes, though it's at least tolerable when running as a widget.  Before turning the app into a widget, I used a combination of a Timer and a Handler and this seemed to work OK.

```
timerHandler = new Handler();
timer = new Timer(timerHandler, drawAction);
```

Any thoughts on how I might accomplish my goal (assuming it's possible) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IMHO, attempting to update an app widget more than once per minute would be grounds for dismissal. If you want to update something on the home screen that frequently, write a home screen. That way, among other things, you know when you are in the foreground or not and can avoid needless work when you are not in the foreground.

Comment: Thank-you for your opinion.  I've read all the cautions about this.  In this case, it is something the user has some control over.  In addition, the frequency of display varies; it is only 20/sec under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to agree with CommonsWare here-  a widget should not be updating that frequently, widgets should be infrequently updating summaries.  Once a second is ok if you're a clock.  Anything else should be every few seconds or few minutes.

ANyway, timers and handlers are a pretty old school way of doing animations.  Choreographer would be the correct way of getting a regular callback, every 1 60th of a second.  Even better, use the Android Animator and Interpolator objects to get regular updates and call setAnimation on your view, avoiding any cheduling of your own.

Comment: Note, though, that the approaches in your second paragraph require a running process and do not take into account the variable amount of IPC overhead of communicating with app widgets.

Comment: I've addressed the frequency issue for widgets above.  With respect to using some animation-specific capability, there are two issues.  One is that what I am doing is not strictly animation.  The frequency varies based on any number of factors.  The other is that at this point I'd prefer not to do a major rewrite of my app if I can avoid it.